# How to save an image read via camera.capture_continuous (format rgb) and save it to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, camera, raspberry-pi, google-coral

I read the raspi camera via `camera.capture_continuous(stream,format='rgb', use_video_port=True, resize=(width, height)` to feed it to the Coral Edge USB Accelerator. This works perfectly. But now I want to save certain images (depending on the analysis) to the harddrive.

I'm a python beginner... `file.write` didn't work. I assume it is because I get some kind of raw rgb image data and not a jpg.

I'd like to be able to store the image as jpg. Can anyone suggest what function to use?

Update:

---

I tried the following

```
import argparse
import os
import io
import time
from collections import deque
import numpy as np
import picamera
from PIL import Image
import edgetpu.classification.engine

def main():

  stream = io.BytesIO()
  engine = edgetpu.classification.engine.ClassificationEngine(args.model)

  for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream,
                                       format='rgb',
                                       use_video_port=True,
                                       resize=(width, height)):
      stream.truncate()
      stream.seek(0)
      input = np.frombuffer(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
      results = engine.ClassifyWithInputTensor(input, top_k=3)
      
      ...
      
      image = Image.fromarray(input.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
      image.save("imgs/image_" + str(i) + ".jpg")
```

But only got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mio.py", line 85, in <module>
    main()
  File "mio.py", line 75, in main
    image = Image.fromarray(input.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2529, in fromarray
    size = shape[1], shape[0]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Say you are recording 640x480 pixel RGB images and you saved one to disk with 921,600 bytes. You can easily convert it later to a JPEG or PNG with **ImageMagick** like this `convert -depth 8 -size 640x480 RGB:yourfile result.jpg`

Comment: what would be possible - but I prefer to directly save it in the correct format if possible

Comment: Please make sure your code has all the necessary `import` statements and everything required to make it **Minimal Complete and Verifiable** as required by StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it with the following line

```
image = Image.frombuffer('RGB', (width,height), streamValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) library to save images to disk. Something like:

`pip install Pillow numpy`

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
pixels = np.array([[[255, 0, 0], [0, 255, 0]], [[0, 0, 255], [255, 255, 0]]])
image = Image.fromarray(pixels.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
image.save('out.jpg')
```

Comment: `for foo in camera.capture_continuous(stream,
                                                 format='rgb',
                                                 use_video_port=True,
                                                 resize=(w,h)):
                stream.truncate()
                stream.seek(0)
                input = np.frombuffer(stream.getvalue(), dtype=np.uint8)
                results = engine.ClassifyWithInputTensor(input, top_k=3)
image = Image.fromarray(input.astype('uint8'), 'RGB')
` leads to the following error:

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: plz add this code as well as the complete traceback to end of the question with the 'Update' title.

Comment: Check image mode: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes

Comment: sorry.. does not help me.. I read rgb and I write create the image from rgb.. why should it not work?

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution :) You can post it as an answer here and accept it. If it helpes someone in future they'll upvote your answer.